# Debug doesn't work (Version 2.3)

Tags: debugging, debug, xdebug

I tried all ways to enable debug but it doens't work.
I modify all box on dashboard about debug on "Yes". I tried to use command line with "bin/magento setup:config:set --enable-debug-logging=true" and cleaning cache but it still doesn't working.
(Version 2.3)

Comment: Did you change your scope to "store view"?

Comment: yes i did it but nothing changed

Comment: Is this clean magento installation?

Comment: the question might sound stupid, but what do you expect to happen? how do you verify that "It's not working"

Comment: it should appear some red rows which should have write the block name and path name

Comment: Sounds like you are talking about template hints, run following command: ```php bin/magento dev:template-hints:enable ```